# SAP Middleware Connector ArgumentException Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm developing an application which uses an SAP.Middleware.Connector from SAP AG (version 3.0.2).

This application executes an RFC in the background (using Task.Run) but after a few minutes, the app crashes:

> ```
> ArgumentException caught in DefaultDomain: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute .
> Uncaught Exception in DefaultDomain
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.KeyCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcSessionManager.UpdateSessions(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.Executioncontext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>   at System.Threading.Executioncontext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
>   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
>   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.FireNextTimers()
>   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.AppDomainTimerCallback()
> ```
>
> [image: img]

This is the code of the RFC execution:

```
return Task.Run(() =>
ConexionSAP cSap = new ConexionSAP();
cSap.ConectaSAP();
RfcDestination rfcDest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(cSap.rfc);
            
RfcRepository rfcRep = rfcDest.Repository;
IRfcFunction function;
function = rfcRep.CreateFunction("XXXNAMEOFTHEFUNCTIONXXX");

//import parameters
RfcSessionManager.BeginContext(rfcDest);
function.Invoke(rfcDest);

//export parameters
RfcSessionManager.EndContext(rfcDest);
});
```

Please, can you help please with this?

Comment: You mention "using Task.Run" in your question, but that's not shown in your code? Are you a calling this code from a `foreach` loop?

Comment: If you call it synchronously (i.e. without `Task.Run(…)`) does it work OK?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry I missed that part, question edited.

Comment: Yeah, it works, but it takes too long the execution of the RFC, and block me the UI, so that its the reason to put it in that Task.Run.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the full stack trace as text?

Comment: Yeah, sure I´m on it. That´s all the stack trace that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help!

I'm running on the answer of this.
If you use **BeginContext** and **EndContext** on a **Thread**, the connector will try to renew the connection but now the thread containing the connection its gone causing the error, Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

The solution was to delete the **BeginContext** and **EndContext** line, everything is fine and working.

Comment: your counclusion is false - the problem is actually that the threading underneath is done wrong